# php assigning by reference,passing by reference

Tags: php

I understand there is *assigning by reference* (`$b = &$a`) and *passing a variable by reference* `function foo( &$var )`

I don't understand  how this works: `return($var & 1) & return(!($var & 1))` ? I saw this fragment [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
<?php

    function odd($var)
    {
        // returns whether the input integer is odd
        return($var & 1);
    }

    function even($var)
    {
        // returns whether the input integer is even
        return(!($var & 1));
    }

    $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

    print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
    // Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 3 [4] => 5 ) //1,3,5 ..odd

    echo "<br>";

    print_r(array_filter($array2, "even")); 
    //Array ( [0] => 6 [2] => 8 [4] => 10 [6] => 12 ) 6,8,10,12...even

    // I tested with these variables
    echo "<br><br>";

    $var=22;

    echo(odd($var));     //prints 0
    var_dump(odd($var)); //int 0


    $var=11;

    echo (even($var));   //prints nothing
    var_dump(even($var));//boolean false

?>
```

Comment: So is your question about passing by reference? or about bitwise operators?

Comment: sorry i didn't even know whether it is passing by reference or what..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` is a [bitwise "and"](http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.bitwise.php) here, not a reference operator. `& 1` checks whether the least significant bit it set. For odd numbers it is set, for even numbers it isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. it confused me,so it just checks the least significant bit for determining odd and even numbers,simply in a single line of code...